# Speed change from a slicing layer

Tags: prusaslicer

I did a slicing of a small piece that only has 22 layers. How can I configure the PrusaSlicer software to work at a speed of 60 mm/s up to the sixth layer and from the seventh layer onwards to assume a speed of 40 mm/s?